# python - mock - class method mocked but not reported as being called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

learning python mocks here. I need some helps to understand how the *patch* work when mocking a class.

In the code below, I mocked a class. the function under tests receives the mock and calls a function on it. In my assertions, the class is successfully called, but the function is reported as not being called.

I added a debug print to view the content in the function under tests and it is reported as called.

My expectation is the assertion *assert facadeMock.install.called* should be true.  Why is it not reported as called and how do I achieve this?

Thank you.

install/__init__.py

```
from .facade import Facade

def main():
    f = Facade()
    f.install()
    print('jf-debug-> "f.install.called": {value}'.format(
        value=f.install.called))
```

test/install_tests.py

```
import os
import sys
# allow import of package
sys.path.insert(0,
                os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from unittest.mock import patch

import install

@patch('install.Facade') # using autospec=True did not change the result
def test_main_with_links_should_call_facade_install_with_link_true(facadeMock):
    install.main()

    assert facadeMock.called
    assert facadeMock.install is install.Facade.install
    assert facadeMock.install.called   # <-------------------- Fails here!
```

output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/jfl/ubuntu-vim, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item                                                               

test/install_tests.py jf-debug-> "f.install.called": True
F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________ test_main_with_links_should_call_facade_install_with_link_true ________

facadeMock = <MagicMock name='Facade' id='140679041900864'>

    @patch('install.Facade')
    def test_main_with_links_should_call_facade_install_with_link_true(facadeMock):
        install.main()
    
        assert facadeMock.called
    
        assert facadeMock.install is install.Facade.install
    
>       assert facadeMock.install.called
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = <MagicMock name='Facade.install' id='140679042325216'>.called
E        +    where <MagicMock name='Facade.install' id='140679042325216'> = <MagicMock name='Facade' id='140679041900864'>.install

test/install_tests.py:21: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test/install_tests.py::test_main_with_links_should_call_facade_install_with_link_true - AssertionError: assert False
============================== 1 failed in 0.09s ===============================
```

**[edit]**

Thank you to @chepner and @Daniil Fajnberg for their comments. I found the cause of the problem.

The problem can be reduced at:
*`install/__init__.py`* receives an instance of Facade when calling Facade() in main().
This instance is not the same as the one received in parameters of the test. They are different instances.

to retrieve the instance received in main(), do:

```
    actualInstance = facadeMock.return_value
    assert actualInstance.install.called
```

And it works!

Thank you. That really helps me understand the working of mocks in python.

**[/edit]**

Comment: Yeah, patching imports are tricky. Have you tried patching `install.facade.Facade` instead?

Comment: `facadeMock.install` produces a *new* `Mock` instances every time it is used. So the mock that gets called is not the one whose `called` attribute you are looking at. I think it should work if you do something like `install_mock = facadeMock.return_value.install`, then check if `install_mock.called` is true.

Comment: You are mocking the entire `Facade` class, then creating an instance of it in `main`, which produces a new mock object and then you are calling that new mock object's `install` method. You never call the initial mock's `install` method.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. Your comment helped me figure out the issue. I edited the question to add the answer, giving you credits.

Comment: Thank you @Daniil Fajnberg. Your comment helped me figure out the issue. I edited the question to add the answer, giving you credits.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method to solve your problem; it is *empirical* but it works.

To pass your test I have modified it as you can see below:

```
@patch('install.Facade') # using autospec=True did not change the result
def test_main_with_links_should_call_facade_install_with_link_true(facadeMock):
    install.main()

    assert facadeMock.called
    assert facadeMock.install is install.Facade.install

    #assert facadeMock.install.called   # <-------------------- Fails here!
    install_called = False
    for call_elem in facadeMock.mock_calls:
        if call_elem[0] == "().install":
            install_called = True
            break
    assert install_called == True
```

### Mock objects `facadeMock` and `f` are distinct

`facadeMock` is a mock object created in the test code and it is used by the production code during your test to create the mock object `f`  by the instruction:

```
f = Facade()
```

In the production code `f` is a mock object (that is an instance of the class `Mock`) because it is created by the Mock object `Facade` that is exactly `facadeMock`.

But `f` and `facadeMock` are 2 different instances of the class `Mock`.

Below I show the id values of `facadeMock`, `Facade` and `f`:

```
facadeMock = <MagicMock name='Facade' id='140449467990536'>
Facade = <MagicMock name='Facade' id='140449467990536'>
f = <MagicMock name='Facade()' id='140449465274608'>
```

The id for `facadeMock`, `Facade` are equal but are different from the id of `f`.

### The attribute mock_calls

When your test code is executed the function `install.main()` execution causes the definition of the attribute `mock_calls` for the mock object `facadeMock`.

This attribute is a list of complex elements.
If you check the first field (I mean the field in position 0) of each one of this element you can find the name of the methods of the mock that are called.

In your case you have to found `install` and to do this you have to look for `().install`.
So my test checks all the element of `mock_calls` and only if `().install` is found set the variable `install_called=True`.

I hope that this answer can help you.